# Do we really need a captcha for established users?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-bydesign

It seems like every time I ask a question (although may not be every time) I get asked to fill out a captcha. I fully understand the value of this for new users, but if I am logged as a user that has established some reputation, I see little value in continuing to ask if I am a human. Can this be changed to only be asked for new users?

Comment: Note, I was not asked for this question, but was for the prior question I asked.

Comment: I can't think of the last time I saw this.  Doing something suspicious?

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary. I access the site from home, work, and my phone. The last time I received the captcha I was at home. My work does route all of our traffic out of another state, but the IP is always the same and I believe I had the captcha many times before I started working there.

Comment: @Kellenjb, look at jeffs comment on the answer.

Comment: Why do we need a captcha at all for someone that has already gone thru the process and created a account?

Comment: @OlinLathrop Your comment is essentially the exact question I was asking. According to the link in Jarrod's answer it is so that if you get a bug on your computer as a "trusted" user, the bug can't spam stack exchange. The answer also says that it only suppresses the captcha for 5 minutes... I am sure glad that I am not seeing a captcha every 5 minutes though.

Comment: Sometimes those captcha things are hard to read even for humans.  I often get it wrong on the first try.  I think they need to lighten up a bit and stop treating us like criminals.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Every now and then I get captcha's that are upside down... I have no idea how to type those :-)

Answer (score 1):

After you solve a captcha, we [suppress them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69010/3) for a small interval.  Looking at the http logs, we're not seeing anything unusual.

If you see a spate of captchas, please let us know.

Comment: generally when people bring this up, they have done something like disable JavaScript or otherwise manipulated their browser settings away from default values. Is that true in this case?

Comment: @Jeff nope, nothing changed out of the usual. Is meta treated seperate from the main site? Thinking back I probably always see it on meta, but never on the main site.

Comment: And in case you didn't see my comment on the question, my normal habits are phone, work, and home. My work does route my traffic out from another state, but this is done outside of browser settings.